# Strange php error after updating old view

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

As part of our migration to latest civi for numerous sites, we had to make an adjustment to a drupal calendar views on the existing, live older civi site (4.0.5).

(We're upgrading all sites to 5.12 - need to keep this site online until go live.)

After running latest php upgrades on the drupal dbase and modules we lost calendar event view display. We attempted to get civievents to display on the calendar, weren't successful, then decided to create events as drupal content type "Event Data" as a workaround.

We tested and re-created about 70 such civievents as content type "Event Data."

All seemed fine and working at that point. Every event data type showed on the calendar and we considered the issue solved.

A short time later we received support indicating the site was no longer letting the site admins log-in - at all.

We are now locked out of the site completely, e;.g. each time we attempt to log in -or access anything civi related on the site - we see the error. The drupal pages all display.

Error reporting shows the following :

E_ERROR Error in file ?civicrm_entity.module? at line 499: Call to undefined method CRM_Utils_Hook::singleton()

We've tried nearly everything, disabling civicrm_entity, related modules, civicrm entirely, and still cannot log in. We only saw this after adjusting the view, all else seemed okay after running the upgrades.

Any ideas on how to fix - or at least what to disable - to bring the site back or at least restore the admin log in?

We should be able to restore an older version but the same issue we thought we had solved with the calendar will likely reappear. Admittedly that's better than no access, but still the calendar issue.

Updating with common backtrace errors from the Config Logs :

Apr 19 10:58:35  [info] $backTrace =
 site.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php,
 backtrace, 303
 site.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php,
 fatal, 482
 site.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php,
 getFields, 236
 site.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.php,
 getListingFields, 155
 site.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.php,
 preProcess, 256
 site.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php,
 run, 348
 , profile,
 site.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php,
 call_user_func, 191
 site.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module,
 invoke, 443
 , civicrm_invoke,
 /usr/local/share/drupal-7.66/includes/menu.inc, call_user_func_array, 527
 site.com/web/index.php,
 menu_execute_active_handler, 27

Running Drupal 7.66

Any assistance appreciated...
H

Comment: does drush uli fail to get you logged in too?

Comment: hey Pete, looks like we're back on track now. We disabled Civicrm and all related modules.  Ran single pending update and cleared all drupal cache tables then re-enabled  civicrm and nec. modules. now site is restored with calendar now displaying event data nodes. A workaround that works. We'll attempt to get the civicrm calendar displaying civievents  on 5.12 (dealing with some sort of plug in rss error there). Will close it out here and open a new one if we can't get that going.

Thanks for the assistance.